# React-native render method of 'HeaderConfig'

Tags: react-native, render

I'm getting an error that's pointing to an issue with a dependency in react-native components but I can't find posts that mention how to resolve this. It points to error being in 'react-jsx-runtime.development.js'

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render
> method of 'HeaderConfig".

Here is my index.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
// react-native components 
import { Text, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
// like react router
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router'

// import contants to style 
import { COLORS, icons, images, SIZES } from '../constants'

// import components. cmd+click to confirm scope 
import { Nearbyjobs, Popularjobs, ScreenHeaderBTN, Welcome } from '../components'

// const home = functional component where we can return view with text inside
const Home = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite }}>
                <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite },
                        headerShadowVisible: false,
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <ScreenHeaderBTN iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension='60%' />
                        ),
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <ScreenHeaderBTN iconUrl={icons.profile} dimension='100%' />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

The file was actually named ScreenHeaderBtn and I was mistakenly importing 'ScreenHeaderBTN'. ScreenHeaderBtn fixed this.